# Adjust properties of 3D object and camera faster

Tags: objects, interface, camera, properties

I need to adjust position parameters for a specific object and x shift value parameter for the camera frequently.
What are my options to make this process more comfortable? - I want to avoid that I have to switch selection between camera and object to show the respective parameter input boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pin any properties tab to the editor.
Click the pin icon, and the tab will stay active even if you select other objects.

[image]